# Jquery hyperlinks triggering

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, triggers

```
<a href="myuglypage.php">click</a>
```

**Does JQuery allow you to trigger a link event without actually clicking on "click"??**

**There is any alternative to window.location??**

Thanks

Luca

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, is the `click()` method not doing what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

You break the back button, HTTP Referer is not populated etc. You will also have to manually use jQuery to listen for the click event and then do the relocation. Just triggering a click event on the anchor will not simulate clicking the link.

So yes, you're essentially stuck using an event handler and window.location.

Some more in-depth discussion here: [jQuery Click Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343811/is-there-a-jquery-click-method)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this

```
window.location.href = "myuglypage.php";
```

This is diffrent from  `window.location.replace()` method. It i more similer to clicking the link.

Comment: Really doesn't answer his question if you ask me.