# Press a button on keydown? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple code for keydown. At the moment is fading in div1. I am looking for a code which will press a button?. I know I have to add onClick event on the button but I tried couple of ways which didn't gave me any results.

```
jQuery(document).one('keydown', 'g',function (evt){
$("#Div1").fadeIn();
return false;});
```

The button source is: (Which on click it does show's me #Div1 again. I want to add the same for the Div1.):

```
<ul id="button">
<li><a class="btn1" id=btn1 href="#Div1"></a></li>
</ul>
```

You probably think why would I want that? The reason is that Div1 is a form which on button click makes some animations where on FadeIn it doesn't. 
Thanks alot.

Comment: Sorry but you have no button in your code. Naming some element "button" does not make it a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).one('keydown', 'g',function (evt){ 
        $("#btn1").click(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery trigger to fire the button click. [Trigger API](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

It would look something like this.

```
$("#btn1").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $("#btn1").trigger("click");
```

A similar question has been posted:

[Is there a jQuery Click method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343811/is-there-a-jquery-click-method)