# opening a new tab using javascript

Tags: javascript

Iam trying to Open a URL in New Browser Tab by passing it to window.open function. I don't have anchor element here and this action is not triggered by an on-click event.

```
FileOpen.openDocument = function(file_id){
  var URL = <ANOTHER_SITE>+"/index.do?docId="+file_id;
  window.open(URL,"_newtab");
}
```

This invokes the Window as a popup and not in new tab in Chrome. In Firefox it opens in new tab but the URL is wrong in both Browsers as shown below

```
<CURRENT_SITE>/jsp/<ANOTHER_SITE>/index.do?docId=<ID>
```

Can anyone suggest how to implement this. I wish to open the URL in a new tab in all the browsers.

Thanks,
Prasanna

Comment: About that new tab, i think Chrome just dont support it... you can find some info [HERE](http://superuser.com/questions/56176/google-chrome-open-pop-ups-in-new-tab) and it seems to be registered as issue in Chrome [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=10511)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your new url starting with http:// ?
When it doesn't, it takes the uri and just adds it.

Comment: Thanks Vice2doom, now the URL opens correctly. But still it opens as Popup. I want it to open in a New Browser tab. Just as it opens while clicking on an anchor with href and target="_blank". 

Any suggestion for how to get this behavior ?

Comment: well I'm not sure of this but you can make a link on the website (hidden if you don't want to show it) and then use the .click() method of JQuery.

Comment: Any idea how i can trigger a click on an anchor using JQuery with href defined ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343811/is-there-a-jquery-click-method on this link you can find some more information about how to do it.